# How to get specific fields to be shown in the search results?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, umbraco7

I'm using ezSearch package installed into Umbraco 7.6.
What I am trying to do is to get specific fields to be always shown in the search result under the pageName that has the word that the user is looking for,

So for example I have two properties in the homepage (heading1 and homeText)

And the code for (search results) in the macro as following:

```
@helper RenderContentResult(SearchViewModel model, IPublishedContent result)
{
    <div class="ezsearch-result">
        <h2><a href="@result.Url">@result.Name</a>XX</h2>

        @foreach (var field in model.PreviewFields.Where(field => result.HasValue(field)))
        {
            <p>@Highlight(Truncate(Umbraco.StripHtml(result.GetPropertyValue(field).ToString()), model.PreviewLength), model.SearchTerms)</p>

            break;
        }
    </div>
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since result is an IPublishedContent you can access whatever property you want, e.g.

```
result.GetPropertyValue<string>("homeText")
```

or

```
@(result.GetPropertyValue<string>("homeText"))
```

anywhere in `RenderContentResult` depending on the needed [Razor syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor)

Comment: @Ray _it doesn't work_ is not a very specific problem description. *What* doesn't work? Do you get errors? What does your code look like using my solution?

Comment: I'm not a developer so maybe i didn't put it in the right way, walk me through pls if that's possible, many thanks

Comment: `Line 238:
Line 239:    </div>
Line 240:                       result.GetPropertyValue<string>("homeText")
Line 241:}
Line 242:@helper RenderMediaResult(SearchViewModel model, IPublishedContent result)`